# IAP Non-consumable item restore with unnecessary update transactions and strange transaction

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

**Summary**

When restore non-consumable items on Sandbox environment, I received strange `SKPaymentTransaction` object:

- `transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased`
- `transaction.originalTransaction != nil`

I think originalTransaction property is only assigned when transactionState is `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored`.

This is iOS bug ?

**Details**

My IAP code is like a following.

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
 updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {

  for (SKPaymentTransaction* transaction in transactions) {   // (1)
    switch (transaction.transactionState) {
      case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing: {
        break;
      }
      case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased: {   // (2)
        BOOL success = [self _provideContents]
        if (success) {
          [queue finishTransaction:transaction];
        }
        break;
      }
      case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored: {    // (3)
        BOOL success = [self _resotreContents];
        if (success) {
          [queue finishTransaction:transaction];
        }
        break;
      }
      ...
   }
}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue 
 removedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
   // (4)
}
```

}

My App has 200 of non-consumable IAP Items.
My Test sandbox user already purchased all 200 of IAP items.

I run my App with a debugger and tap "restore" button on my App, and logged in with above sandbox user account.

I set breakpoint on //(1) line. When a debugger break on //(1) line,  I confirmed `transactions.count == 200` and `transactions[0].transactionStete == SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored`.

And I stopped execution my app on //(1). My App process is terminated suddenly.
In this time, 200 of non-finished transactions are remained.

I restart App and //(1) line is executed again, and //(3) line is executed 200 times. So all transactions are finished.

But I tapped home button on my device and relaunch my app, Unexpectedly, //(2) line is executed about 80~90 times. That case's transaction is:

- `transaction.transactionState == SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased`
- `transaction.originalTransaction != nil`

Why some transaction is updated again ?
Why isn't transactionState Restored, is it Purchased ?

This strange behavior is only occurred with a sandbox user who purchased 200 of IAP items. With another sandbox user who purchased 10 or 20 items purchased, it's not occurred.